# Prevent printing for specific sheet if specific cell is empty

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to prevent printing capabilities if my T5 cell on my sheet 2 is empty. My code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
    If IsEmpty(Range("T5")) Then
    Cancel = True
    MsgBox ("Insert Employee Number in REPAIR WORKSCOPE tab")
    End If
End Sub
```

I have tried doing the ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet 2" before the `IsEmpty` command, but I only get error when I try to run.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: run-time error '9' subscript out of range

Answer (score 0):

You can use And to check for both conditions.

```
If IsEmpty(Range("T5")) And ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet 2" Then
```

Answer (score 0):

`Range` always resolves to the `ActiveSheet` unless otherwise qualified explicitly.

Try this:

```
If IsEmpty(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("T5"))
```

Note:

> ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet 2"

This most likely raises an error because this is not how you "activate" a worksheet, and if another sheet is "active" *and* `Sheet2` already exists, then you're going to get a Key error.  You could do:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
```

And then your original code would work.

My preference would be to use the other method of explicitly qualifying the range to the desired worksheet, and avoid the need to Activate anything :)

If you want to prevent printing **only** for Sheet 2, then do:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
    If ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet2" And IsEmpty(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("T5").Value) Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox ("Insert Employee Number in REPAIR WORKSCOPE tab")
    End If
End Sub
```

If you want to prevent **all** printing, based only on the `T5` value in Sheet2:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
    If IsEmpty(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("T5").Value) Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox ("Insert Employee Number in REPAIR WORKSCOPE tab")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried the second code, but for some reason anytime I try to use the ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet2" command it highlights the code yellow and gives an error.

Comment: I figured it out, googled the error code and all I had to do was use the sheets code name and the code ran. Thanks everyone for the help